# Content creator trying to download my data from patreon

Tags: web-scraping, google-chrome-devtools, patreon

I am a content creator on patreon.  I have hundreds of posts there and I am slowly migrating my content to a Wordpress website.  I'm hoping to find a way to download all my content from Patreon at once, because it's literally taken me months to do it one post at a time.

In the past I have built Python scrapers for websites, and I hoped that would work in this case, but when I look at the Developer Tools on Chrome, in the Elements section I can see each post as a `<li>`, but when I look at the Source code, I don't see that stuff, so I guess the website is using some sort of script or code to make it so these list items only load in the GUI but not within the source code itself?  I'm really a newbie at this stuff, and I can already hear people getting mad at the vagueness of my post.  I looked at their API documentation and from what I can tell, there is no way to get post info with that. https://docs.patreon.com/#introduction

To make this post even more annoying, I can't easily show my page because I have to be logged in to see my content.

So, is there a way to parse data from a website even it it's not showing up in the source code?  Or, is there a way to print out all the code that I'm seeing in the Elements tab of the Chrome Developer Tools and I could parse the data from that?